# Working around not being able to subclass a path dependent type

Tags: scala, subclass, private, path-dependent-type

I am looking for a way to restrict invocations of certain objects. Given a transactional system which defines a reference type, a transaction type, and an identifier:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] {
  type Ref[A]
  type Tx <: Txn[S]
  type ID
}
```

I would like to be able to mix in a trait that can be used to create mutable references:

```
trait Mutable[S <: Sys[S]] {
  def id: S#ID
  protected final def newRef[A](implicit tx: S#Tx): S#Ref[A] =
    tx.newRef[A](this)
}
```

And the reference factory is defined as part of the transaction:

```
trait Txn[S <: Sys[S]] {
  /* private[Mutable] */ def newRef[A](mut: Mutable[S]): S#Ref[A]
  def newID: S#ID
}
```

Now, the problem is, in the following structure I can create references with false contexts:

```
def newStruct[S <: Sys[S]](cross: Mutable[S])(implicit tx: S#Tx) = 
  new Mutable[S] {
    val id        = tx.newID
    val allowed   = newRef[Int]
    val forbidden = tx.newRef[Int](cross) // shouldn't compile...
  }
```

I would like to disallow the last call. Obviously, I cannot make `newRef` in `Txn` private to `Mutable`, because `Mutable` is not an enclosing class of `Txn`. I also would like not to use package privacy, as one can easily break into `newRef` by defining an object in that package.

Ideally I would like this:

```
trait Sys[S <: Sys[S]] { trait Mutable }

class MyStruct[S <: Sys[S]] extends S#Mutable { ... }
```

which would solve all the problems. But this is disallowed, since `S` in `S#Mutable` `"is not a legal prefix for a constructor"` in scalac's universe....

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put the definition of `Txn` in `Mutable`'s companion object, then make it private to `Mutable`.  Not sure if there are further implications, though.

```
trait Sys[ S <: Sys[ S ]] {
   type Ref[ A ]
   type Tx <: Txn[ S ]
   type ID
}

object Mutable {
  trait Txn[ S <: Sys[ S ]] {
    private[Mutable] def newRef[ A ]( mut: Mutable[ S ]) : S#Ref[ A ]
    def newID : S#ID
  }
}

trait Mutable[ S <: Sys[ S ]] {
   def id: S#ID
   protected final def newRef[ A ]( implicit tx: S#Tx ) : S#Ref[ A ] =
      tx.newRef[ A ]( this )

}

// Or maybe you could declare type Txn in the package object...
trait Txn[ S <: Sys[ S ]] extends Mutable.Txn[S]

object Foo {
  def newStruct[ S <: Sys[ S ]]( cross: Mutable[ S ])( implicit tx: S#Tx ) = 
    new Mutable[ S ] {
      val id        = tx.newID
      val allowed   = newRef[ Int ]
      val forbidden = tx.newRef[ Int ]( cross ) // doesn't compile...
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, with the `trait Txn[ S <: Sys[ S ]] extends Mutable.Txn[S]` it's actually not so bad.